# Automatically categorizing after associating text in two columns.

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I associate a category (could be from a drop down list) to text/name in another column automatically after associating the first one. Example with categorizing transactions in a list. Column A is the categories-(grocery, utility, restaurant) Column D is name of transactions. (Walmart) should be grocery, but I want every Walmart appearing Column D after that to automatically become grocery in Column A. Also every Food Lion after associating it once, etc.

Comment: You can use a `IF()` condition or a `VLOOKUP` function to achieve this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have researched and found some answers that I am trying to understand how to execute.  I find VLOOKUP challenging as it seems my data is too large. I have about 65 categories and 525 name variations on 1800 transactions.  Creating the table as I go along and enter transactions is part of what I am trying to figure out. I found a similar question, but as far as I can tell, none of the answers are quite what I want. Also I don't really understand the answers without further study. ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062929/categorizing-bank-transactions-in-excel)

Comment: Post a part of your data using Google docs so that we can see what would be the best solution

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IZ7TZinaxt6F6X9nq1xKPS4wbbPNNMpetkYAFouh4sM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have created this chat room for the discussion http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37957/discussion-between-caroline-and-prasanna. Please click on the link if you want to elaborate your requirement on chat

Comment: I don't think I have enough "reputation points" to interact in the chat. I didn't see anyway to respond.